# How to show up a duplicate in python?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

there is my data set (head()): 
[image]

I know there is one duplicate in user_id. I check it with this query: 
sum(df2.user_id.duplicated())

Now I want to know this user id. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply loc to get the rows which are duplicated.

```
   duplicated_rows = df2.loc[df2.user_id.duplicated()]
```

or to get id,

```
   duplicated_ids = df2.loc[df2.user_id.duplicated(), 'user_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dup = df2["user_id"]
df[dup.isin(dup[dup.duplicated()])].sort("user_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

A `pandas` one-liner: if `df` is your original dataframe

```
dupl_id = df[df.duplicated(subset='user_id', keep='first')]['user_id']
```